# How to use background images with owl carousel

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'd like to use [owl carousel](http://owlgraphic.com/owlcarousel/) with background images rather than `<img>` tags, like used in http://driveshift.com/car/c10148. However, every example included in the plugin site uses the `img` tags.

When you inspect the [Shift](http://driveshift.com) carousel, it uses url images as data-src attributes and then owl carousel auto converts them to background images. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 10):

Check out the example code at https://owlcarousel2.github.io/OwlCarousel2/demos/lazyLoad.html

> LazyLoad HTML strucutre requires class="owl-lazy" and data-src="url_to_img" or/and data-src-retina="url_to_highres_img". If you set above settings not on  but on other DOM element then Owl will load an image into css inline background style.

Therefore, if you use `<div>` instead of `<img>`, you'll get your desired result.

```
<div class="owl-lazy" data-src="http://placehold.it/350x250&text=3">
```

Note that you may need to add some CSS to the `div` for it to look correctly. Hope that helps!

Answer (score 4):

I was somewhat looking for a similar solution to your question and following the solution proposed by Paulshen I had it working. Basically  I created my carousel elements with div and set the data src to the image url 
pulled from the database and then manipulated it with css and media queries to get it working correctly as he suggested.

Hope this helps, find below:

HTML:

```
<div class="owl-carousel owl-theme">
<div class="slide-item owl-lazy" data-src="https://placehold.it/350x250&text=3"></div>
<div class="slide-item owl-lazy" data-src="https://placehold.it/350x250&text=3"></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.slide-item{ position: relative;
background-repeat: no-   repeat;
background-position: top center;background-size: cover;}
```

Css Media Queries:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 39.9375em) {
.slide-item{min-height: 280px;background-position: center;    background-size: cover;} }
@media screen and (min-width: 40em) {
.slide-item{ height: 360px; min-height: 360px;} }
@media screen and (min-width: 64em) {
.slide-item{ height: 600px; min-height: 600px;}}
```

JS:

```
$('.owl-carousel').owlCarousel(
{
    lazyLoad:true,
    items:1,
    autoplay: true,
    smartSpeed: 1500,
    nav:true,
    dots: true,
    loop : true,
  }
);
```

Answer (score 2):

Example:

HTML:

```
<div class="owl-carousel">
    <figure style="background-image:url(loading.gif)" data-src="image-real.jpg"></figure>
    <figure style="background-image:url(loading.gif)" data-src="image-real-2.jpg"></figure>
    <figure style="background-image:url(loading.gif)" data-src="image-real-3.jpg"></figure>
    <figure style="background-image:url(loading.gif)" data-src="image-real-4.jpg"></figure>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.owl-carousel figure {width:100%; height:450px; background-size:cover; background-position:center center; background-repeat:no-repeat;}
```

JS:

```
$('.owl-carousel').owlCarousel({
    onTranslated: function(me){
        $(me.target).find(".owl-item.active [data-src]:not(.loaded)").each(function(i,v){
            $(v).addClass("loaded").css("background-image", "url("+$(v).attr("data-src")+")");
        });
    }
});
```

Don't need use lazyLoad functions. Use animations on css to personalize your effects.

Comment: Thanks Robert, your sample was inspiring. Feedback: 

When using the javascript in your sample, 3 slides always appear, regardless of the item parameter value.

To avoid seeing the loading gif initially:
<figure style="background-image:url(https://placehold.it/350x250&text=1)"></figure>

I was able to use lazy loading with the figure tag by moving the background to css:
.owl-stage div {
  background-image:url(loading.gif);
  background-position:center center !important;
  background-repeat:no-repeat !important;
}
The ideal would be to wait a second before showing the loading icon.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to display different images (size or aspect ratio) on smaller screens, then you can use padding-top with background-image.

**HTML**

```
<section>
  <div class="owl-carousel owl-theme">
    <div class="slider"><a class="one" href="#"></a></div>   
    <div class="slider"><a class="two" href="#"></a></div>
    <div class="slider"><a class="three" href="#"></a></div>
  </div>
</section>
```

**CSS**

```
section {
  max-width: 1200px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.slider a {
  background-position: center;
  background-size: cover;  
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  padding-top: 18.33%; /** HEIGHT : WIDTH x 100 **/
}
.one {
  background-image: url('https://picsum.photos/1200/220?random=1');
}
.two {
  background-image: url('https://picsum.photos/1200/220?random=2');
}
.three {
  background-image: url('https://picsum.photos/1200/220?random=3');
}
```

Full code and demo on **[CODEPEN](https://codepen.io/dragoeco/pen/RmvBma)**