# Owl Carousel Height Adjust

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, carousel, owl-carousel

I am building a site that features an owl carousel at the top of the home page. The site is in its preliminary stages, and I'm having an issue with the carousel.

I want the carousel to remain responsive, while the images adjust so they fill the **entire** height of the window/screen. In other words, I don't want the images to resize; just to recenter as the window gets smaller. Right now, they are just shrinking when the window resizes.

This is my current code:

**HTML**

```
    <section id="sidebar">
        <div id="owl" class="owl-carousel"> 
            <div class="item" id="item-1"><img src="assets/img/motel.jpg" alt=""></div>
            <div class="item" id="item-2"><img src="assets/img/gas.jpg" alt=""></div>
            <div class="item" id="item-3"><img src="assets/img/sofia.jpg" alt=""></div>
       </div>
    </section>
```

**JS:**

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#owl").owlCarousel({
            navigation: true,
            slideSpeed: 300,
            paginationSpeed: 400,
            items: 1,
            autoplay: 3000,
            stopOnHover: true,
            loop: true,
        });
    });
```

**CSS:**

```
    #owl .item img {
        display: block;
        widows: auto;
        height: 100%;
        min-height: 523px;
    }
```

Here is a link to the full site (so far) on github: https://jnikkiyoke.github.io/project/

Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easy way is to remove the `<img/>` tag and use `background` instead :

```
.item {
    height: 100vh;
    width: 100%;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

#item-3{
    background-image: url("assets/img/gas.jpg");
}
```

You can also remove the `min-height` on `#owl .item img`

You may also want to add `height: 100vh;` and `width: auto;`. Use [media queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/CSS/Requ%C3%AAtes_m%C3%A9dia/Utiliser_les_Media_queries) for different ratios.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I have already tried what you suggested, and it hasn't worked. What happened this time is the images weren't displayed at all. I have tried the media queries, and just got frustrated! All I need is for the height to remain constant across screen sizes. It's ok if the entire image is not in view, but it must fill the screen length wise.

Comment: Hey nikkiy, there is an example with slick-carousel. https://jsfiddle.net/jondion/78xvdjrp/2/

Comment: jonathandion - it looks like you're using slick instead of just a plain owl. Do you suggest doing this instead? I was trying to use owl, and wanted to eventually apply a rewind effect when it got to the last slide. Also, if I use slick, should I use the theme css that goes with it?

Comment: Both carousels are really good but many prefer Slick over Owl. I prefer Slick because it's more flexible. Yes, you may want to start with ```slick-theme.css``` for a base theme and overwrite the style for your needs. If you want to stick with Owl and use background-images instead you should look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30665809/how-to-use-background-images-with-owl-carousel. Hope this help.

Comment: Thanks! You've been a lot of help!