# Owl carousel with background image not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, owl-carousel

I've the following owl carousel snippet from my app. The demos in owl carousel's github page has used `<img>` tag for it's slider. Following suggestions from around the web I've used `background-image`:

```js
$('.demo-slider').owlCarousel({
  loop: true,
  margin: 10,
  nav: false,
  touchDrag: 1,
  dots: 0,
  responsive: {
    0: {
      items: 1
    },
    600: {
      items: 1
    },
    1000: {
      items: 1
    }
  }
})
```

```css
.owl-carousel .item {
  width: 100%;
  height: 512px;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-image: url("https://source.unsplash.com/1024x512/?coffee");
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/OwlCarousel2/2.3.4/owl.carousel.min.js"></script>

<div class="owl-carousel owl-theme demo-slider">
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
</div>
```

But the above snippet doesn't produces any slider. What I've missed here ?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/31376958/4375843

Comment: @jbe already went through it. Did find any clue for this issue.

Comment: i've written an answer. did it solve your problem?

Answer (score 0):

You missed dot for class selector `item` in CSS:

```
.owl-carousel .item {
```

and I am not sure that you can use `height: auto;`
you need to set specific height like `height: 50px;`

Comment: updated question as you have pointed out. But result is the same.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution!!!

When you try the background image you have to update the height in your style.

E.g.

`.owl-item {
...
}`

> for Window height:-

`min-height: 100vh`

> for fixed height:-

`min-height: 100px`

**note**: you can change "`min-height`" to just "`height`" as per you requirement.

Comment: By default, the carousel height is set by images height.

Answer (score 0):

As described [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31376958/4375843), if you use `<div>` instead of `<img>`, you'll get a background image.

Additionally you have to provide some css to make it look right.

Here is a working example

```js
$('.owl-carousel').owlCarousel({
  items: 4,
  lazyLoad: true,
  loop: true,
  margin: 10,
});
```

```css
.owl-lazy {
    height: 200px;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center center;
}

.owl-carousel .owl-item .owl-lazy:not([src]), .owl-carousel .owl-item .owl-lazy[src^=""] {
    max-height: none !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/OwlCarousel2/2.3.4/owl.carousel.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/OwlCarousel2/2.3.4/assets/owl.theme.default.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/OwlCarousel2/2.3.4/assets/owl.carousel.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>


<div class="owl-carousel owl-theme">
    <div class="owl-lazy" data-src="https://placehold.it/350x250&text=4"></div>
    <div class="owl-lazy" data-src="https://placehold.it/350x250&text=5"></div>
    <div class="owl-lazy" data-src="https://placehold.it/350x250&text=6"></div>
    <div class="owl-lazy" data-src="https://placehold.it/350x250&text=7"></div>
    <div class="owl-lazy" data-src="https://placehold.it/350x250&text=8"></div>
    <div class="owl-lazy" data-src="https://placehold.it/350x400&text=9"></div>
    <div class="owl-lazy" data-src="https://placehold.it/350x400&text=10"></div>
    <div class="owl-lazy" data-src="https://placehold.it/350x450&text=11"></div>
</div>
```